# Running multiple nodes in different physical locations

Tags: go-ethereum, uniswap, ethers.js, txpool

**The goal**

I'm currently running a sniping bot that interacts with a private node. The goal is to detect new ERC20 token launches and place orders.

After a while of testing this setup I noticed that some account (bots) always have their transactions included before mine, although all transactions (mine and theirs) have same gas.
After some doing some research, I came to a conclusion that they mostly are running multiple nodes in different locations, thus picking up the launch transaction from the mempool before my node does.

**My approach**

Start by extending my setup to run 3 node (US, EUR and ASIA), and run my bot on all of the nodes. This way I'll be able to pick up the launches faster, depending on where they were originated from.

**My questions**

First I want to know if my analysis is correct.
If so, can anyone suggest how I can synchronize between my nodes so that if one picks up a launch first, the other 2 stop listening on the mempool (to avoid having multiple orders being placed).

At the end I would like to point out that I'm still a beginner in the Ethereum world, so I might be missing something in the whole picture.

Any comments or suggestions are much appreciated.

Cheers!